# Views: How to display a grouped taxonomy list with node count?

Tags: 7, views, taxonomy-terms, nodes

I'm building a classifieds section of a website. Is it possible to create a grouped taxonomy list (by parents) with a node count at the end?

**Essentially this is what I want to appear:**

[image: Classifieds Section with taxonomy]

**Currently, this is my BuySell content type node.
I have two taxonomy vocabularies: BuySell Category and Location.**

[image: BuySell Node]

**Lastly, here is a snapshot of my taxonomy vocabulary buysell:**

[image]

I'm trying to use Views to create the list, however I'm not sure how to get them to group nicely together by parent terms. I can output all terms though.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi Chris, I am wondering if you managed to figure this out, and if you also sorted the classified landing pages by location (ie.  Only show the count for Victoria when Victoria is selected, count for Vancouver when Vancouver is selected etc).    I have a similar task at hand and if you could share your solution it would really help :)

Comment: Hi Danielle, I've put this project on hold so I haven't progressed much with it. Here's something you can try: Go to Taxonomy Views > Add Header > Global: Results Summary.
It should show a list of taxonomy terms with view count in brackets.

Answer (score 2):

It has been a while since I've done this, but I recall doing it with Views and setting the `Taxonomy Term` as the argument and using the Glossary option.

Alternatively, there are several snippets for doing this type of thing, as I recall. You can find a few of them here:

1. [Show a list(x) of taxonomy terms with node counts](http://drupal.org/node/494026)
2. [Drupal API - taxonomy_get_tree](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!taxonomy!taxonomy.module/function/taxonomy_get_tree/6) ([or for D7](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!taxonomy!taxonomy.module/function/taxonomy_get_tree/7))

In both cases, check the comments for various implementations or tweaks to functionality.

Answer (score 1):

This [view](http://drupal.org/node/343294#comment-5224920) might help as well. It is using the summary function of contextual filters.

```
$view = new view;
$view->name = 'tags';
$view->description = '';
$view->tag = 'default';
$view->base_table = 'node';
$view->human_name = 'Tags';
$view->core = 7;
$view->api_version = '3.0-alpha1';
$view->disabled = FALSE; /* Edit this to true to make a default view disabled initially */
/* Display: Master */
$handler = $view->new_display('default', 'Master', 'default');
$handler->display->display_options['title'] = 'Tags';
$handler->display->display_options['access']['type'] = 'perm';
$handler->display->display_options['cache']['type'] = 'none';
$handler->display->display_options['query']['type'] = 'views_query';
$handler->display->display_options['query']['options']['query_comment'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['exposed_form']['type'] = 'basic';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['type'] = 'full';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['options']['items_per_page'] = '50';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['options']['offset'] = '0';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['options']['id'] = '0';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['options']['expose']['items_per_page_options_all'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['style_plugin'] = 'list';
$handler->display->display_options['row_plugin'] = 'fields';
/* Relationship: Content: Taxonomy terms on node */
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['term_node_tid']['id'] = 'term_node_tid';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['term_node_tid']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['term_node_tid']['field'] = 'term_node_tid';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['term_node_tid']['required'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['term_node_tid']['vocabularies'] = array(
  'tags' => 'tags',
  'article_category' => 0,
  'book_hierarchy' => 0,
  'vocabulary_1' => 0,
  'group' => 0,
  'organization_taxonomy' => 0,
);
/* Field: Taxonomy term: Name */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['id'] = 'name';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['table'] = 'taxonomy_term_data';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['field'] = 'name';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['relationship'] = 'term_node_tid';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['label'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['alter']['alter_text'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['alter']['make_link'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['alter']['absolute'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['alter']['external'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['alter']['replace_spaces'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['alter']['trim_whitespace'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['alter']['nl2br'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['alter']['word_boundary'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['alter']['ellipsis'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['alter']['strip_tags'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['alter']['trim'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['alter']['html'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['element_label_colon'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['element_default_classes'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['hide_empty'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['empty_zero'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['hide_alter_empty'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['link_to_taxonomy'] = 1;
/* Sort criterion: Content: Post date */
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['created']['id'] = 'created';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['created']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['created']['field'] = 'created';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['created']['order'] = 'DESC';
/* Contextual filter: Taxonomy term: Name */
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['name']['id'] = 'name';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['name']['table'] = 'taxonomy_term_data';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['name']['field'] = 'name';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['name']['relationship'] = 'term_node_tid';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['name']['default_action'] = 'summary';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['name']['default_argument_type'] = 'fixed';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['name']['default_argument_skip_url'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['name']['summary']['sort_order'] = 'desc';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['name']['summary']['number_of_records'] = '1';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['name']['summary']['format'] = 'default_summary';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['name']['summary_options']['items_per_page'] = '25';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['name']['glossary'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['name']['limit'] = '0';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['name']['transform_dash'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['name']['break_phrase'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['name']['add_table'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['name']['require_value'] = 0;
/* Filter criterion: Content: Published */
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['id'] = 'status';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['field'] = 'status';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['value'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['group'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['expose']['operator'] = FALSE;
/* Display: Tags */
$handler = $view->new_display('page', 'Tags', 'page');
$handler->display->display_options['path'] = 'tags';
$translatables['tags'] = array(
  t('Master'),
  t('Tags'),
  t('more'),
  t('Apply'),
  t('Reset'),
  t('Sort by'),
  t('Asc'),
  t('Desc'),
  t('Items per page'),
  t('- All -'),
  t('Offset'),
  t('term'),
  t('Page'),
);
```