# Problem viewing my view with relationships

Tags: 7, views

I created a view to display my content type "subject" I searched it as a forum (I do not use the forum module).

My problem is when I add relationships to my view to calculate the number of topics and comments. The view only displays forums containing comments.

How to view all forums (even those that have no comments) ?

Here is an export of my view :

```
$view = new view();
$view->name = 'forum';
$view->description = '';
$view->tag = 'default';
$view->base_table = 'taxonomy_term_data';
$view->human_name = 'Forum';
$view->core = 7;
$view->api_version = '3.0';
$view->disabled = FALSE; /* Edit this to true to make a default view disabled initially */

/* Display: Master */
$handler = $view->new_display('default', 'Master', 'default');
$handler->display->display_options['title'] = 'Liste des forums';
$handler->display->display_options['use_more_always'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['use_more_text'] = 'plus';
$handler->display->display_options['group_by'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['access']['type'] = 'perm';
$handler->display->display_options['cache']['type'] = 'time';
$handler->display->display_options['cache']['results_lifespan'] = '3600';
$handler->display->display_options['cache']['results_lifespan_custom'] = '0';
$handler->display->display_options['cache']['output_lifespan'] = '3600';
$handler->display->display_options['cache']['output_lifespan_custom'] = '0';
$handler->display->display_options['query']['type'] = 'views_query';
$handler->display->display_options['query']['options']['distinct'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['exposed_form']['type'] = 'basic';
$handler->display->display_options['exposed_form']['options']['submit_button'] = 'Appliquer';
$handler->display->display_options['exposed_form']['options']['reset_button_label'] = 'Réinitialiser';
$handler->display->display_options['exposed_form']['options']['exposed_sorts_label'] = 'Trier par';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['type'] = 'none';
$handler->display->display_options['style_plugin'] = 'views_bootstrap_table_plugin_style';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['columns'] = array(
  'name' => 'name',
  'description' => 'description',
  'nothing' => 'nothing',
  'title' => 'title',
  'comment_count' => 'comment_count',
  'expression' => 'expression',
);
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['default'] = '-1';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['info'] = array(
  'name' => array(
    'sortable' => 0,
    'default_sort_order' => 'asc',
    'align' => '',
    'separator' => '',
    'empty_column' => 0,
  ),
  'description' => array(
    'align' => '',
    'separator' => '',
    'empty_column' => 0,
  ),
  'nothing' => array(
    'align' => '',
    'separator' => '',
    'empty_column' => 0,
  ),
  'title' => array(
    'sortable' => 0,
    'default_sort_order' => 'asc',
    'align' => '',
    'separator' => '',
    'empty_column' => 0,
  ),
  'comment_count' => array(
    'sortable' => 0,
    'default_sort_order' => 'asc',
    'align' => '',
    'separator' => '',
    'empty_column' => 0,
  ),
  'expression' => array(
    'align' => '',
    'separator' => '',
    'empty_column' => 0,
  ),
);
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['bootstrap_styles'] = array(
  'striped' => 'striped',
  'bordered' => 'bordered',
  'hover' => 'hover',
  'condensed' => 0,
);
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['responsive'] = 0;
/* Relation: Terme de taxonomie : Contenu utilisant Forum */
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['reverse_field_sujet_forum_node_1']['id'] = 'reverse_field_sujet_forum_node_1';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['reverse_field_sujet_forum_node_1']['table'] = 'taxonomy_term_data';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['reverse_field_sujet_forum_node_1']['field'] = 'reverse_field_sujet_forum_node';
/* Relation: Commentaire : Dernier commentaire */
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['cid']['id'] = 'cid';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['cid']['table'] = 'node_comment_statistics';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['cid']['field'] = 'cid';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['cid']['relationship'] = 'reverse_field_sujet_forum_node_1';
/* Relation: Commentaire : Auteur */
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['uid']['id'] = 'uid';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['uid']['table'] = 'comment';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['uid']['field'] = 'uid';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['uid']['relationship'] = 'cid';
/* Relation: Commentaire : Contenu */
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['nid']['id'] = 'nid';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['nid']['table'] = 'comment';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['nid']['field'] = 'nid';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['nid']['relationship'] = 'cid';
/* Champ: Terme de taxonomie : Nom */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['id'] = 'name';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['table'] = 'taxonomy_term_data';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['field'] = 'name';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['label'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['exclude'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['alter']['word_boundary'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['alter']['ellipsis'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['element_label_colon'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['link_to_taxonomy'] = TRUE;
/* Champ: Terme de taxonomie : Description du terme */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['description']['id'] = 'description';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['description']['table'] = 'taxonomy_term_data';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['description']['field'] = 'description';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['description']['label'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['description']['exclude'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['description']['element_label_colon'] = FALSE;
/* Champ: Global : Texte personnalisé */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nothing']['id'] = 'nothing';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nothing']['table'] = 'views';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nothing']['field'] = 'nothing';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nothing']['label'] = 'Forums';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nothing']['alter']['text'] = '<h2 class="forum-title">[name]</h2>
[description]';
/* Champ: COUNT(DISTINCT Contenu : Titre) */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['id'] = 'title';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['field'] = 'title';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['relationship'] = 'reverse_field_sujet_forum_node_1';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['group_type'] = 'count_distinct';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['label'] = 'Sujets';
/* Champ: Contenu : Nombre de commentaires */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['comment_count']['id'] = 'comment_count';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['comment_count']['table'] = 'node_comment_statistics';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['comment_count']['field'] = 'comment_count';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['comment_count']['relationship'] = 'nid';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['comment_count']['label'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['comment_count']['exclude'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['comment_count']['element_label_colon'] = FALSE;
/* Champ: Global : Expression mathématique */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['expression']['id'] = 'expression';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['expression']['table'] = 'views';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['expression']['field'] = 'expression';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['expression']['label'] = 'Contributions';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['expression']['precision'] = '0';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['expression']['expression'] = '[title]+[comment_count]';
/* Champ: Suivi - Utilisateur : Date de mise à jour */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['changed']['id'] = 'changed';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['changed']['table'] = 'tracker_user';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['changed']['field'] = 'changed';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['changed']['relationship'] = 'reverse_field_sujet_forum_node_1';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['changed']['label'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['changed']['exclude'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['changed']['element_label_colon'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['changed']['date_format'] = 'short';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['changed']['second_date_format'] = 'long';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['changed']['format_date_sql'] = 0;
/* Champ: Global : Texte personnalisé */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nothing_1']['id'] = 'nothing_1';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nothing_1']['table'] = 'views';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nothing_1']['field'] = 'nothing';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nothing_1']['label'] = 'Dernière contribution';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['nothing_1']['alter']['text'] = '[changed]';
/* Critère de filtrage: Vocabulaire de taxonomie : Nom système */
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['machine_name']['id'] = 'machine_name';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['machine_name']['table'] = 'taxonomy_vocabulary';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['machine_name']['field'] = 'machine_name';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['machine_name']['value'] = array(
  'forum' => 'forum',
);

/* Display: Page */
$handler = $view->new_display('page', 'Page', 'page');
$handler->display->display_options['path'] = 'forum';
$translatables['forum'] = array(
  t('Master'),
  t('Liste des forums'),
  t('plus'),
  t('Appliquer'),
  t('Réinitialiser'),
  t('Trier par'),
  t('Asc'),
  t('Desc'),
  t('field_sujet_forum'),
  t('Dernier commentaire'),
  t('auteur'),
  t('Contenu'),
  t('Forums'),
  t('<h2 class="forum-title">[name]</h2>
[description]'),
  t('Sujets'),
  t('.'),
  t(','),
  t('Contributions'),
  t('Dernière contribution'),
  t('[changed]'),
  t('Page'),
);
```

Here is a screenshot of my view (In Relationship, the "Require this relationship" boxes are not checked) :

[image]

Here is the result :

[image]

Here is the content of the forum "Cuisine" :

[image]

Here are the full forums that should be posted (sorry I changed the titles). As you can see, it lacks in the previous view the forum without comments.

[image]

Comment: are you requiring the comment relationship either in the relationship itself or when you bring in the fields?

Comment: @longboardnode I need the relationship to calculate the number of comments and topics. But I do not understand why relations reduce view.

Comment: You can have the relationship available but not require it. If you require it, then you will only see nodes with comments. If you add the relationship but not require it, you will see all nodes and then be able to filter the fields  with/without comments and do other logic. Look at this [DO tutorial](https://www.drupal.org/node/1920288)

Comment: @longboardnode I do not understand, because I did not check the boxes "Require this relationship" in "Relationships". Why is my view reduced ?

Comment: Hmmm, weird... can you post a screenshot of your actual view page? should be admin/structure/views/view/forum/edit

Comment: @longboardnode Yes. I've updated my question.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, your "Forums" are taxonomy tags, then you count the number of "Subject"-type nodes that have this tag, and their total comments? So "Cuisine" and "Maison" are the terms?

Comment: @longboardnode Yes that's exactly it.

Comment: I think the issue is you have a realtionship to (field_suject_forum) in your first count (COUNT DISTINCT Content: title) but that relationship is attached to Last Comment.. therefore it will only count the nodes with comments. Your count should be on titles with term Forum...

Comment: @longboardnode I tried, but I can not.

Comment: @longboarsnode I tried, but I can not. Did you have an example of an exported view ? Thank you

Comment: I think you're better off handling the logic and counting using [hook_views_pre_render](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/hook_views_pre_render/7.x-3.x) so load all the fields into the view, then override the counts using custom code inside that hook.  Here's a [nice tutorial](http://agaric.com/blogs/altering-views-results) on this.

Comment: [This](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/24526/views-how-to-display-a-grouped-taxonomy-list-with-node-count?rq=1) might be helpful

Comment: @longboardnode I have another question, if you are interested http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/221750/view-of-terms-with-column-of-last-updated-node

Comment: lol yeah, I suspect you will run in to many more questions with this implementation. The issue IMO is that you are trying to stack the relationships and logic on top of the taxonomy terms and that becomes a bit difficult to do in views alone. If you look at [Advanced Forum module](https://www.drupal.org/project/advanced_forum) it does exactly what you are trying to achieve I think, and you can see how many pages and components it requires to make this work.

Comment: @longboardnode I want to do this without additional module.

Comment: Then my suggestion is to download the advanced forum module and check out how it performs these tasks. There are already views and templates in place there that do exactly what you are trying to do, so you can probably copypaste from there as needed into your own module. Sorry that's the best I know... maybe others have a better solution